# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\cos t\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}+e^t.y=0$

Tags: differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\cos t \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}+e^t.y=0$

I have attempted with `DSolve[{y''[x] - Cos[x]*y'[x] + y[x]*E^x == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]` which gives `DSolve[{E^x y[x] - Cos[x] Derivative[1][y][x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, True, True}, y[x], x]`

What is going wrong here and how do I find the solution ?

Comment: `y[0],y'[0]`are predefined, restart your kernel!. Now Mathematica evaluation shows the input (after a while) and shows that MMA can't solve the ode!

Comment: The solution is the trivial solution `y[x] = 0` (by inspection).  `DSolve` won't find it because it can't find the general solution, and it doesn't seem to be able to solve by inspection.

Comment: You can still use NDSolve to get a numerical solution.

Answer (score 1):

This return `y[x]=0`

```
Plot[NDSolveValue[{y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[t] - Cos[t] y'[t] + E^t y[t] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 
10}][x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]